# Handle TypeError inside a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to handle the TypeError inside the function and not out of it. Is it posible?? I need to get a message when I forgot the args instead of the program failing

```
def numbers(a, b):
   print(a + b)

numbers()

>>>TypeError: numbers() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'a' and 'b'
try:
    numbers()
except TypeError:
    print("ARGS")
```

SOLUCION:

```
def numbers(*args):
    try:
        if len(args) == 2:
            a = args[0]
            b = args[1]
            print(a + b)
        elif len(args) > 2:
            print("Max args: 2")
        else:
            print("Add 2 args")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: No, you can't handle that inside the function, because the error means it *never gets called*.

Comment: What you've pointed to is not possible simply because you're getting the error because of calling the function in a wrong way. The problem does not lie in your function but the way you've called your function.

Comment: what about default arguments? `def numbers(a=None, b=None)`? and then handle the arguments explicitly in the function?

Comment: You could add defaults to the function parameters, so omitting them won't raise an error, if that is what you mean.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist that should be the answer here... IMO

Comment: This is yelling for a counter-question: why would you want to not raise an error if a function is called with incorrect arguments? That should fail as soon as possible. In other some languages, it would fail before even starting the application, for a good reason - to see the error as soon as possible.

Comment: @zvone in the particular example given in the question that might be true, but in the general case this can actually be useful, like imitating Java's function overload for example (have a few ways of calling the same function with different number of arguments)

Comment: All of you please, read again the post with the solucion I found

Comment: why don't you want the program to fail? what happens if you expand this and have another method that runs assuming that `numbers()` completed successfully.

Comment: Why are you trying to reengineer exceptions? It's as if instead of just letting the exception tell the user whats wrong, you want to catch every possible case that would lead to an exception, print what it would say in that situation, and ignore it. Also, what exception are you even catching? Nothing you're doing could cause an exception, so why try-except it. You keep adding more and more code without knowing what you're doing, which is a recipe for disaster

Comment: @MartinBouhier in the solution you posted, there is no actual need of the `try/except`. The possible errors are handled in the `if`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could refactor it do handle arguments in a cleaner way:

```
def numbers(a=None, b=None): 
   if a==None or b==None: 
      return "Not enough arguments, two requried" 
   print(a + b) 

numbers()
```

Comment: For any future readers: don't do that. The default behaviour (the exception) is much better than that. Always. Default arguments are very useful for different uses, though.